# amplify push causes local changes to be reverted instead of pushed to the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I've made some changes to the authentication schema in the cloudformation.yml file and updated the parameters.json file to add 2 custom attributes in AWS Amplify. Whenever I try to push them to the cloud using "amplify push" the command instead pulls the current state of the cloud and reverts my local changes. Even after recloning my repository it still does the same thing. I'm running Amplify CLI v4.27.1 and Node.js v12.18.3. Any ideas on why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue, and solved it by making sure only  **one amplify folder** with all files exist on the root.

in my case i had a another copy of an earlier setup called **amplify_bk**

removed it and did a `amplify pull`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue just now and resolved it by telling the cli specifically what i want to push.

In my case my function was updated but the api was not, so i did

`amplify push function`